# Editing /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network doesn't chane the hostname

Tags: hostname

We have tried both the /etc/hosts and also /etc/sysconfig/network. Edited both files and service network restart. Yet the hostname is showing as localhost.localdomain. How to resolve on this? Googling almost all talking about the same method too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this answer : 
[How to change the hostname of a RHEL-based distro?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12829/how-to-change-the-hostname-of-a-linux-machine-using-terminal?rq=1)

Have you tried running the command :

```
hostname new_hostname
```

where "new_hostname" would be value you are trying to set ?

Comment: it works but will it be permanent there? How about the other steps with regards to /etc/sysconfig/network and /etc/hosts? Must I still edit those ?

Comment: Yes, you should edit those files too. The two files are for the "permanent" changes, the "hostname" command is for "on the fly" change.

Comment: ok let me test I am not too sure about the /etc/hosts how where and what to change exactly can you please verify as some said just put beside the 127.0.0.1 hostname is this correct?