# Script To Update Multiple Hostnames

Tags: ssh, hostname, readline

Needing a script to read row by row, then ssh into the machine and update the hostname of the machine, then exit and continue with the next row. We have a cvs file that contains the previous hostname and the current hostname of the machine.

What we are needing is to update a list of 220 hostnames. The image is an example of the file that contains hostnames we need to update. We need the script to ssh into the current hostname and then update the hostname and then continue to the next one.

Example input file:

```
D1-2-199 D1-2-150
D1-2-150 D1-2-165
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) show us an example of this csv file and ii) explain what you want done in more detail. Why would the script move to the next row? What wouyld the next row have and what should be done with it?

Comment: edited the information.

Comment: Thanks but please don't post screenshots of text. Post the text itself directly. We need to see the actual format since the character delimiting the fields is important. Use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it look clear. So, for example, you would need to run `ssh D1-2199` and change its name? What operating systems will these be running? WHat user will you be connecting as? Do you have passwordless access set up?

Comment: Also, an idea of how you normally would update the hostname manually individually if you didn't have such a script, eg what file or files do you need to edit? or if you dont know in the first place, then, what distro the target machines are running , if all the same, etc since different distros set slightly hostnames differently : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12829/how-to-change-the-hostname-of-a-linux-machine-using-terminal#12832

Comment: Yes, we will need to ssh into the name D1-2-199 and change it's hostname to the new one. If the hostnames are the same we need to be able to skip those ones. We are running Linux Mint. Not sure what you mean about the passwordless access setup? We normally run this by logging into root on the computer. Example ssh d1-2-199 -l root or if we are at the machine we do /bin/su -. The files we would need to update are /etc/hosts and /etc/hostnames

Comment: I meant whether you need to enter root's password or if you have ssh keys set up that allow you to login (safely) but with no password. If you don't, I strongly urge you to do so if you're going to be managing multiple machines.

Comment: No, we normally enter in the root password to access this information. Do you know how I could go about or find information to use ssh keys? Only two people will be able to run this script.

Comment: Just a clarification about the input example, the OP says it is csv, but doesn't csv mean 'comma separated values'. The example  `D1-2-199 D1-2-150` lacks commas, is this a minor typo or just how these particular csvs will be formatted?

Comment: Its a typo. I didn't format it correctly. There's two columns within the CSV old and new.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to do something like this:

```
while read old new
do
    ssh root@$old "hostname $new"
done < names.csv
```

That will read through each line of your `names.csv` file, `shh` to the appropriate server and change its name.