# What's the default file for `hostname`?

Tags: linux, hostname

Heyo! I'm currently working on a non-lfs system from scratch with busybox as the star. Now, my login says:

```
(none) login:
```

Hence, my hostname is broken. `hostname` brings me `(none)` too.

The guide I was following told me to throw the hostname to `/etc/HOSTNAME`. I've also tried `/etc/hostname`. No matter what I do, `hostname` returns `(none)` - unless I run `hostname <thename>` or `hostname -F /etc/hostname`. Now obviously, I don't want this to be done every time somebody freshly installed the distro -- so what is the real default file, if not `/etc/hostname`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On a GNU/Linux system, `man 5 hostname` states that "The `/etc/hostname` file configures the name of the local system that is set during boot using the `sethostname`(2) system call". I couldn't say whether this applies in your context, but does `hostname` work if you write the host name to `/etc/hostname` and reboot?

Comment: @fra-san thanks for the comment! If I `cat /etc/hostname` I get `semc`, my hostname. But no matter how many times I reboot, still `hostname` itself is `(none)`. I'm using Busybox init, btw.

Comment: On some systems the hostname is read from the first entry in /etc/hosts (yes, even loopback)

Comment: @roaima The first line in `/etc/hosts` is `127.0.1.1 semc` - nothing. But, I wrote this *after* the initial install, not inside of the `.tar.gz` that I then untar to a partition. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `hostname` commands in common toolsets, including BusyBox, do not fall back to files when querying the hostname.
They report solely what the kernel returns to them as the hostname from a system call, which the kernel initializes to a string such as "(none)", changeable by reconfiguring and rebuilding the kernel.
(In systemd terminology this is the *dynamic hostname*, a.k.a. *transient hostname*; the one that is actually reported by Linux, the kernel.)
There *is no* "default file".

There's usually a single-shot service that runs at system startup, fairly early on, that goes looking in these various files, pulls out the hostname, and initializes the kernel hostname with it.
(In systemd terminology this configuration string is the *static hostname*.)
For example:

- In my toolset I provide an "early" `hostname` service that runs the toolset's `set-dynamic-hostname` command after local filesystem mounts and before user login services.  The work is divided into stuff that is done (only) when one makes a configuration change, and stuff that is done at (every) system bootstrap:

  - The external configuration import mechanism reads `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/HOSTNAME`, amongst other sources (since different operating systems configure this in different ways), and makes an amalgamated `rc.conf`.
  - The external configuration import mechanism uses the amalgamated `rc.conf` to configure this service's `hostname` environment variable.
  - When the service runs, `set-dynamic-hostname` doesn't need to care about all of the configuration source possibilities and simply takes the environment variable, from the environment configured for the service, and sets the dynamic hostname from it.
- In systemd this is an initialization action that is hardwired into the code of `systemd` itself, that runs before service management is even started up.  The `systemd` program itself goes and reads `/etc/hostname` (and also `/proc/cmdline`, but *not* `/etc/HOSTNAME` *nor* `/etc/default/hostname` *nor* `/etc/sysconfig/network`) and passes that to the kernel.
- In Void Linux there is [a startup shell script](https://github.com/void-linux/void-runit/blob/95ad0a971eccddba4779ad153860fff3764d123a/core-services/05-misc.sh) that reads the static hostname from (only) `/etc/hostname`, with a fallback to the shell variable read from `rc.conf`, and sets the dynamic hostname from its value.

If you are building a system "from scratch", then you'll have to make a service that does the equivalent.
The BusyBox and ToyBox tools for setting the hostname from a file are `hostname -F "${filename}"`, so you'll have to make a service that runs that command against `/etc/hostname` or some such file.

BusyBox comes with runit's service management toolset, and a simple runit service would be something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
exec 2>&1
exec hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering et al. (2016). [`hostnamectl`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostnamectl.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). "[`set-dynamic-hostname`](http://jdebp.info./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/set-dynamic-hostname.xml)".  *User commands manual*.  nosh toolset.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). "[`rc.conf` amalgamation](http://jdebp.info./Softwares/nosh/guide/rcconf-amalgamation.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). "[external formats](http://jdebp.info./Softwares/nosh/guide/external-formats.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Rob Landley. [`hostname`](http://landley.net/toybox/help.html#hostname).  *Toybox command list*.  landley.net.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12832/5132

Comment: Awesome explanation! I have little experience writing services in runit/busybox init, but this seems like the way to go! Thank you again!

Answer (score 6):

So you are building this system from scratch and you are asking where the hostname is configured?

The simple answer is that it isn't.  The current hostname is stored inside the kernel and like most things kernel, it doesn't read any files by default.

*Something* in your system startup must read a config file (of your choosing) and set the kernel's hostname.  This must happen every startup.

Answer (score 6):

You can change it from `make menuconfig` when building the kernel.